# Windows 10 manually update from 1703 to 1709

Tags: windows-10

My company handed me a Windows 10 Laptop for Hololens Development.
It is not officially supported by our IT but has some administrative changes made to it. For some reason Windows Update is not working, since it cannot reach the server.

I tried and suceeded in manually installing (almost) all KB Updates for 1703 from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mt679505.aspx).

The feature update jump from 1703 to 1709 seems to be not possible by applying kb fixes. Before, i also already tried the Windows10Upgrade Tool and the MediaCreationTool, both without success.

Is there any method on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: If your IP department is not supporting it, ask them to revert whatever changes stop *you* from “supporting” it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1703 version should be Enterprise edition, this edition cannot be upgraded via Windows10Upgrade Tool and the Media Creation Tool, you need 1709 iso for in-place upgrade.

However, Enterprise edition can’t be downloaded freely from official channel(you need to buy a subscription of Visual Studio Subscriptions or have account to sign in VLSC), third-party website may have iso resources, but can’t guarantee security.

One thing make me confused, since you can manually install kb, it indicates that you are an administrator of system, why not to configure GPO in group policy editor to enable automatic update?

Comment: This worked, but it only downloaded all updates for 1703 and is not upgrading to 1709. Or is it really only possible via iso?